# Can I change the default /// method comment snippet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there any way to change the default C# comment snippet that typing `///` gets you?

For example, can I replace this default comment snippet

```
/// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arg1"></param>
/// <param name="arg2"></param>
public void MyFunction(int arg1, int arg2)
{
}
```

With this one

```
/// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arg1">
///
/// </param>
/// <param name="arg2">
///
/// </param>
public void MyFunction(int arg1, int arg2)
{
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?  I want to change what hitting /// gives me automatically (I don't mean am I allowed to edit the default snippet in the C# text editor).

Comment: Oh, so you want to change the template for it?

Comment: theres a 3rd party extensions called ghostdoc that can do a lot of the work for you.

Comment: @John Yes, I want to edit the default.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'll take a look at that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @John The workaround in that post doesn't have a way to handle the method's (variable number of) parameters.